# How to create a Azure Hosted web interface for Azure ML Pipeline Endpoints

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

This is my simple Azure Machine Learning Pipeline, where the model is written in Python.

[image]

This is the endpoint based on the model, where I can pass my dataset as parameter inside this model to run the experiment and save the outputs in the blob storage. Here, the input datasets are also stored in Azure blob storage

[image]

And this is how we access the endpoint from other client. So, creating models (both simple and complex), publishing them as endpoints and accessing the endpoints from other clients is done.

[image]

Now, the scenario is, we want to create a web interface/form for the business people so that they can upload their dataset in blob, pass it to our model to run the model and see the outputs. We don't want to give them access to ml.azure.com service.

So, is there any Azure hosted web app or service to match my requirements (access endpoints within azure hosted service)? And is there any alternate way to solve it?  I am a beginner in the Azure world.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have published your ML pipeline as an REST endpoint. You should be able to run it using C#/Python/R based on AAD auth. Is that what you are looking for?

Thanks,
Lu